# Explore tab that tracks "topics" in google docs

Tags: text, google-admin-sdk, pattern-recognition, text-analysis

In google docs I noticed there is function in the new Explore tab that tracks "topics". I was wondering how this works and what function it uses to find out the topics specifically about what I'm currently writing about in the google doc?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](https://docs.googleblog.com/2016/09/ExploreinDocsSheetsSlides.html), **Explore** in Docs makes researching and writing reports on the go a whole lot easier. [Topics](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2481802) were added to see search results for topics related to your document. You may also check on this blog about [How to use the new Google Explore feature](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-the-new-google-explore-feature/). Hope this helps!